# Selenium grid mixing up tests between browsers

Tags: c#, selenium, grid, nunit

Lets say i have to open google in 2 browsers, search Test1 in 1st, search Test 2 in 2nd. It opens 2 browsers, writes Test1Test2 in one browser and pass the test. how do i get around it?

it works well if i declare driver in every test function, but this cannot be done if i want to use RemoteWebDriver later to run it on different machines.(because it then uses only one node and doesn't do anything on other) Heard about using non static browser as well, but not sure how to use it, and not sure if that is solution of the problem?

namespace ParallelGrid
{

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class ParallelGrid1
{

    [ThreadStatic]
    public static IWebDriver driver;
      [SetUp]
       public void Setup()
       {

          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
          // driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));//hub id goes here

       }


    [Test]
    [Parallelizable]
    public void Test1()
    {

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Test");
    }


    [Test]
    [Parallelizable]          
        public void Test2()
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Grid");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parallelization to work with NUnit and C# you can only parallelize on Test class at a time. So you have to have one test per class.

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2252